# Does TLS 1.2 have cipher suite specific algorithms/behavior for VerifyData?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am working on a Golang implementation of DTLS, and I am not able to generate a valid value for VerifyData. I have a working example [here](https://gist.github.com/65ca05ca59b2a4d685d2b5918109eed4) this shows my code (and how I get something different then OpenSSL)

printf debugging OpenSSL it looks like the hash of handshake bodies is different then mine. It seems really unlikely, I would assume that I am collecting packets wrong. But putting printf statements before the

The cipher suite is `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` and you can see the entire codebase at https://github.com/pions/dtls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VerifyData (in Finished) always uses the TLS-defined PRF, which for TLS1.2 (and DTLS1.2) is a doubled HMAC using a hash which *can* depend on the ciphersuite. For all pre-existing ciphersuites the D/TLS1.2 PRF uses SHA256, and the new-in-TLS1.2 suite you identified also uses SHA256. (In fact it uses SHA256 *only* for the PRF, because GCM suites don't use HMAC on data.) Some other new-in-TLS1.2 suites use SHA384. Also the *length* of VerifyData in 1.2 is formally dependent on the ciphersuite, but all pre-1.2 suites must use the pre-1.2 protocol size of 12, and all new-in-1.2 suites also do use 12, so in practice there is no difference.

However, going by your gist **your problem is that you included the initial ClientHello and HelloVerifyRequest**, which you shouldn't. See the antepenultimate (second to last, a word I don't get to use very often!) paragraph of section 4.2.1, near the top of [page 18 in rfc6347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#page-18) and [section 4.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.6) which also notes, although this isn't an issue in your example, that if fragmentation is used for transmission you must still hash the *unfragmented* messages.